# Creating text file: IOError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/Users/muitprogram/PycharmProjects/untitled/HR/train.txt'

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, filepath

I am trying to write to create and write to a text file. However, the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/muitprogram/PycharmProjects/untitled/histogramSet.py",  line 207, in <module>
      drinktrainfile = open(abs_file_path, "w")
 IOError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/Users/muitprogram/PycharmProjects/untitled/HR/train.txt'
```

shows up. There are other instances of this in Stack Overflow, however, none of these deal with creating and writing a new file. The directories all exist however- only the file is being created The code that does this is:

```
import os

script_path = os.path.abspath(__file__)  # i.e. /path/to/dir/foobar.py
script_dir = os.path.split(script_path)[0]  # i.e. /path/to/dir/
rel_path = str(j) + "/train.txt" # HR/train.txt
abs_file_path = os.path.join(script_dir, rel_path) #/path/to/dir/HR/train.txt
drinktrainfile = open(abs_file_path, "w")
```

EDIT: train.txt shows up, except as a directory. How do I make it a text file?

Comment: Have you checked that the file is actually a text file and not a directory (as the error message suggests)?

Comment: You're right, it creates a directory. Do you know how to create a text file?

Comment: How did you create the directory?

Comment: The above code creates the filepath/train.txt, where train.txt is a directory

Comment: The code you posted doesn't create a directory. So either the directory gets created in another part of the code, or it was previously created outside the script. Either way, you need to remove the directory from your file system

Comment: Are you creating a directory in a different section of code?  Perhaps `os.mkdirs()` with the full path of the file to open?

Comment: It was created in another part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resource is actually a directory. It was very likely a mistake, as it is not likely that somebody would have created a directory by that name. First, remove that directory, and then try to create and open the file.

You can open the file with `open('/Users/muitprogram/PycharmProjects/untitled/HR/train.txt', 'w')`, assuming that the file does not already exist.

Comment: This is what happened. When I removed the file, as suggested, the files came back as actual text files.